# FadeIn problem in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code but the fadeIn and fadeOut is too fast, I can barely see it.why is that?

```
   $('#post_code_error').html('You Post Code is Out of Range').addClass('post_code_error').show().fadeIn('10000');



   <div id="post_code_error"></div>


   div#post_code_error {
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:300px;
right:100px;
   }

  .post_code_error {
width:100px;
height:10px;
border:1px solid #F00;
background-color: #FFC;
   color:#F60;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your value for the amount of time it should take should not be a string:

```
$('#post_code_error').html('You Post Code is Out of Range').addClass('post_code_error').show().fadeIn(10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.show()` call.  This makes it appear instantly before the `fadeIn()` method is called.  Also use an `integer` for the `fadeIn` method execution time, as opposed to a `string`.